# Dispatching multiple events at the same time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

If the same event is sent from multiple sources say up to seven times, will that be problem in 
flash because its calling the same listener function 7 times. Does Flash events have some management to postpone calling the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the problem, indeed, but it'll be the same issue as if you will add one function as an event listener seven times. And no, Flash is synchronous except for loading external data and workers, so it does not have a method to "postpone" function calls if they are already assigned as event listeners. Otherwise, check `Timer` class and `setTimeout()` method.

Comment: Thanks- I can get make the game work without simultaneous dispatching with a different overall design. Its just a bit more complicated.